# Is it safe to remove this wall?

Tags: walls

I’m trying to figure out if it would be safe to remove this small wall, or if it’s holding up part of the second story? It looks like there is some kind of post and beam through it, but I don’t know how to read these plans. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. Of course it can be done safely (the entire _house_ could be removed safely), but not within the scope of work and risk you probably envision. There's no clear answer here. It depends entirely on your skills and prerogative.

Comment: What will be required to make for a safe removal is not something likely to be determined by a bunch of well-intentioned folks on the internet. It would take a skilled & licensed structural engineer to determine the "safe" way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.   You can remove it with caveats.

You will need an architect to size a beam in the area in yellow below.   You may need point loads below it too at beam endpoints.  After you do this you need to have city OK it and set up temporary supports while installing beam.   Way way out of the realm of a one man DIY job.

It is clear this wall is almost a double point load as it supports a beam and it lines with an exterior wall (garage).   This isn't even something you could remotely guess on as far as replacing the support and your city will need to see plans before knocking it out.

[image]

Comment: Those are big caveats. You basically have the entire second story under temporary support at that point. It's a stretch to call that DIY. Seems like the answer is actually "no".

Answer (score 1):

This is a DIY forum and I hate to say it but there is a time when you need to call in a professional and I think this is one of those times.  If it is load bearing there are things you can do to remove the wall but they need to be calculated and designed by a PE to be safe. Unfortunately your best bet would to go back to the original engineering firm and ask what your options are, and what they could provide you.

Comment: This isn't one of those times. The answer is clearly no.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not sure how this answer differs significantly from yours. You both indicate it _can_ be removed, but only with proper precautions. This answer explicitly recommends get professional help with that while yours recommends a "solid plan" which I would hope most would interpret as "professional help".

Comment: This answer leads with the equivalent of "hire someone". I disagree. That's quite a distinction.

Comment: @isherwood you cant have a "solid plan" for removal without hiring someone in this case, yes you can still do the work your self but with the building codes in this country it MUST have engineered and stamped drawings to pull a permit

Comment: That's just not true. We've addressed building temporary walls to support a few joists on this site. Questions can be asked and answered for something that's fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, for at least three reasons:

1. The near end carries a beam over the adjacent opening. At a minimum, you'd need to retain a post where the end of the wall is now.
2. The far end of the wall carries the laminated beam that's also mentioned nearby. There will be a double or triple stud there which must be retained.
3. Based on 1 and 2, we can assume that the wall itself also carries the floor system above. That support must be retained.

However, you can probably build an opening there if you like. It would require a load-rated header similar to the smaller adjacent beam. You will likely need to support floor joists temporarily while you do that work. You'd want a good understanding of that structure before you begin, and a solid plan to be safe and avoid damage.

Comment: +1,but it's worth spelling out explicitly that said "good understanding of that structure" is impossible to get without a professional taking a look at it. This isn't something one can guesstimate as an amateur and then hope for the best.

Comment: I disagree. A view of the joists resting on the wall clears that all right up.

Comment: That's only going to tell you that this is indeed a load-bearing wall, which we already know from the blueprint. But an amateur can't safely design the header and whatever else is necessary to take over the loads. For example, the wall could be also there to handle shear loads (that tiny piece of wall in the corner between a door and a pile of big windows isn't going to handle much on its own). I'm not a civil or structural engineer but this really sounds like a task for one.

Comment: No wall with that many openings is a shear wall, and the header will be virtually identical with the one for the adjacent opening. Even a lumber yard should have load tables for that. It's not that complicated.